# valgrind reports "Operation not permitted" but permissions seem to be ok

Tags: docker, valgrind

I want to run valgrind to monitor a program binary named `contextBroker` this way:

```
valgrind -v --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --trace-children=yes contextBroker
```

but I get this error message:

```
valgrind: /usr/bin/contextBroker: Operation not permitted
```

(It happens that the `contextBroker` binary is in `/usr/bin/`)

First thing I though was some kind of problem with permissions. However:

- I run the valgrind command as root user
- The permissions of the `/usr/bin/contextBroker` are even wider:

  ```
  ls /usr/bin/contextBroker -l
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7108992 Jun  3 18:15 /usr/bin/contextBroker
  ```

Additional facts:

- The `contextBroker` binary works fine, e.g. if I run it using `contextBroker` it works.
- valgrind version is 3.16.0
- I'm running the valgrind command within a docker container. The same command in the hosting system works (although the valgrind version in the host is slightly different: 3.12.0.SVN)

How I can solve this problem and run valgrind on my process? Thanks!

Comment: You might be running into seccomp issues when running inside the container. Can you pass `--privileged` to your `docker run` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `--privileged` in the `docker run` command line solved this issue.

Thanks Nick ODell for the hint! :)